# When can you label an object a DTO?

Tags: java, c#

[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) says:

> An object that carries data between processes in order to reduce the
>   number of method calls.

What is a process? Could a process be a project in a solution, and could an object that carries data between two projects in the same solution be a DTO, or is it a POCO/POJO?

From the link above, it is pretty clear that Fowler is talking about objects that have to go over the wire and get serialized/deserialized. (web services in example). However, several places I have seen that objects used in projects are called DTO's, without ever being used in conjunction with a remote interface.

Comment: DTOs can also be POJOs/POCOs.

Comment: See this post from Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html

Comment: @EmilLundin Then I guess the whole purpose of DTOs is to shift data in expensive REMOTE calls. Thanks.